# Remove a node after a given node in a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, doubly-linked-list

I'm trying to write a function within my class that takes in a node and removes the node directly after it in a doubly linked list. I have separate functions that remove the first or last node, so this is only in the case of a middle node. I thought the logic of it made sense and my code compiles, but when I try to test it, the program never stops running, so I think it's getting stuck in the while loop. I'm also not sure I'm calling the function correctly. In a doubly linked list called `DLL` populated by `1`, `2`, `3` and `4`, I tried to remove the `3` by putting `DLL.removeAfter(2)` in the main. I see how this is logically flawed, because there is the possibility that there is more than one `2` in a list, but I have no idea what is right.

```
void DoublyLinkedList::removeAfter(const DListNode &p)
{
    DListNode *node = header.next;
    while(node != &p)
    {
        node->next; //iterate to p;
    }
    node->next; //Get to the node after p that is to be deleted
    node->prev->next = node->next;
    node->next->prev = node->prev;
    delete node;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want to replace both instances of `node->next` with `node = node->next`, otherwise you never change the value of `node`.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense.  I implemented the change.  How do I call the function though?

Comment: Can you edit your post to show how you instantiate your `DoublyLinkedList` class and call the function?

Answer (score 0):

```
void DoublyLinkedList::removeAfter(const DListNode &p)
{
    DListNode *node = header.next;

    while(node != &p) {
        node = node->next; //iterate to p;
    }

    DListNode* del_note = node->next; //Get to the node after p that is to be deleted
    node->next = del_note->next;
    del_note->next->prev = node;

    delete del_note;
}
```

Of course, this only finds the `while` breaks when the first element found.

Answer (score 0):

```
void DoublyLinkedList::removeAfter(const DListNode &p)
{
DListNode *node = &header,*NextNode=null;
do {
node = node->next;       
}
while(node != &p);
if(node->next != null) `{
 NextNode = node->next;  //Next Node need to be removed but if next node have more modes attached than it should again assigned to the node then it should get removed....
if(NextNode->next != null)
node->next = NextNode->next;
else
`node->next = null;
}
```